# Typescript/Javascript array push pushes to all arrays in 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

This should be very basic but do not working.
I am trying to push an element on 2d number array on a specific index, but it is inserting element on every index.

```js
let adj = new Array(4).fill(new Array())

adj[0].push(1)
console.log(adj)
```

The output I am getting:

```
[[1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

But I am expecting:

```
[[1], [], [], []]
```

Comment: `[].constructor([1],[],[],[])`;

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib why? just why? yes it gets to the right result but still, why?

Comment: @Amit, how big is your array? is there a reason you use `new Array(4).fill(new Array())` instead of `[[], [], [], []]`?

Comment: @Thomas https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array

Comment: @Thomas
I want a dynamic 2d array where length is fixed for main array. But all internal array size is dynamic.
If I be very specific, I want to create a adjacency list for a graph where each array index means the node number and each index(node) will contant the node which has path/connection to it.

Comment: @Thomas also the length 4 can be changed. it depends on the input. so I am finding generic solution.

Comment: This is a little thin to give you a concrete answer, but I doubt that the adjacency list is the first data-structure that you build for that graph. I'd expect you to have at least a list of nodes. That's where I'd work off: `let ajd = nodes.map(node => []);` or maybe even something like `let adj = nodes.map(node => node.neighbors.map(other => other.index));` just as a concept/approach. Not starting to generate arrays from scratch.

Answer (score 4):

What you're doing with `let adj = new Array(4).fill(new Array())` is just setting `adj` to an array of references to the same array, thus changing one, changes the others.

To fix this do it like this

```js
let adj = Array.from(Array(4), () => new Array());
adj[0].push(1);
console.log(adj)
```

Comment: @Marco Thanks for your workable code. But I have one more confusion then.
Why I need Array.from where this is already an array.

Comment: Because if you try to fill the already existing array it will be filled with references to the same object. When using `Array.from` the arrow function argument `() => new Array()` is called for every element, thus creating a list of unique arrays. In other words creating a 2D array.

Comment: @Marco ok from your idea, finally I have got another two ways. 
`let adj = new Array(4).fill(null).map(() => [])`

`let adj = [...new Array(4)].map(() => [])`